# Why does CSS not show an installed font?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have 3 files in C:\xampp\htdocs\area. They are `index.php`, `styles.css`, and `result.php`. While styling in `index.php` works fine, in `result.php`, it does not work.

In `styles.css`, the `<span>` and `<h1>` tags are styled in Poppins Black and Medium:

```css
h1#font-custom {
    font-family: "Poppins Black" !important; /* This h1 tag is styled. Note: the !important 
    property is used to override the custom-body class which styles the elements inside the 
    body to be Poppins Medium */
}

span#font {
    font-family: "Poppins SemiBold" !important; /* The span tag is also styled */
}
```

In `index.php`, Poppins works fine, but in `result.php`, it doesn't show.

In `result.php`, the HTML looks good:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Result</title>

    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body class="custom-body">
    <?php 
    $height = $_GET['height'];
    $width = $_GET['width'];
    $area = $height * $width;

    echo '<span id="font-custom extra-big">The area is ',$area,'.</span>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '<span id="font-custom extra-big"><a href="index.php">Go back</a></span>';
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help!

Comment: Where is the font stored/being fetched?

Comment: Any extra css imports in index.php?
Also `span#font` doesn't match `<span id="font-custom extra-big">`

Comment: you are using font-custom id for h1 but applied in span. change span id to font and try its working or not

Comment: Also, don't use same id for multiple elements in the same page. CSS does work. But it's a bad practice. Use class instead

Comment: @Skully, the font is stored in C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\POPPINS-BLACK.ttf, POPPINS-SEMIBOLD.ttf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that in results.php the HTML looks good. I'm afraid it doesn't.

Try putting the resulting HTML through a validator and it will tell you that you cannot have more than one `font-custom` id - ids have to be unique.

Also, you are setting `span#font` in the CSS but nowhere in your HTML is there a span with id font.

I think you are wanting to use a class to set the font in various places.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Result</title>

    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body class="custom-body">
    <?php 
    $height = $_GET['height'];
    $width = $_GET['width'];
    $area = $height * $width;

    echo '<span class="font-custom extra-big">The area is ',$area,'.</span>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '<span class="font-custom extra-big"><a href="index.php">Go back</a></span>';
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in your CSS:

```
h1.font-custom {
    font-family: "Poppins Black" !important; /* This h1 tag is styled. Note: the !important 
    property is used to override the custom-body class which styles the elements inside the 
    body to be Poppins Medium */
}

span.font-custom {
    font-family: "Poppins SemiBold" !important; /* The span tag is also styled */
}
```

Remember to change any h1 elements to have a class rather than an id in the same way as we did for the spans.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to clear your cache? Often, when images, and other stuff don't load for me, I clear my cache. Also, it seems that you classes `font-custom-extra-big` doesn't match the `span#font`. Also, if you want all the fonts in a file to default to a certain font, you can write:

```
body {
    font-family: "Poppins Black";
}
```

or

```
#font {
    font-family: "Poppins Black"; /* Note that I didn't put the element name because it is better practice not to do so... */
}
```

Lastly, you can also try using incognito, because then it basically doesn't save your cache.

Hope this was helpful!